# Why use separate php pages instead of one index

Tags: php

For small projects I have been using one index.php page until now, with different ID's to display different actual page contents.

Would it be better to use separate pages instead of the index approach. E.g.

home.php
adduser.php
viewusers.php

instead of
index.php?index=home
index.php?index=adduser
index.php?index=viewusers

Thank you

Edit: I do the actual content generation through classes and separate php files, to keep the code clean and the index.php file uncluttered. I was just wondering what the benefit of using separate php files would be.

Comment: do you get the page contents from a database?

Comment: Yes. Most of the content comes from a db. I keep the actual content generation in different classes and files where possible, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its advisable to split up code that does different things in different files. If you want to unlock that code trough index.php or trough different files, that really doesn't matter, but your code (login etc) should be in seperate files.

you might want to read up on Object Oriented programming i'd guess

Answer (score 1):

if search engines are at all important to you, i would go with approach 1, although you can also use your .htaccess file to make the pages even more friendly, such as 
/ for home
/users for view users, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Having all your code, or all pages, in just one file, quickly becomes a bit of a mess. Use different files for different pages even if index.php would be the one php file that served all the pages. Imho.

Also, try to put all code that is suitable into separate functions (if your not going OOP). Just a tip to keep stuff cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  What does having a single catch-all page containing all of the code do to benefit you?  Separating your concerns into different files, different classes, different separations of any kind allows you to modify one without affecting the others, provided that the newly modified implementation (or entirely new implementation) provides the same outward-facing functionality as the previous one.